# X/A with respect to the quotient topology is Hausdorff?

Tags: general-topology, compactness, connectedness, quotient-spaces

Consider $X = [0,1]$ and $A = (a,b)$ (where $0 < a < b < 1$).

I want to prove $X/A$ is connected and compact.
Here's my approach :

If I take an open cover of $X/A$, the corresponding cover in X will admit a finite subcover since X is compact (w.r.t. the euclidean topology), so the original subcover will also admit a finite subcover. This proves compacity. Then for connectedness I just use the fact that the quotient map is continuous and surjective so its image is connected.

Then I am asked if the space $X/A$ is Hausdorff.

I can see that it is not, because there exist only one point between $a$ and $b$ (which is the point to which the whole set $(a,b)$ is sent to by the quotient map), so any open set containing either $a$ or $b$ will contain this point so their intersection cannot be empty.

Is this the right intuition ? If so how would I formalize it ?

Comment: It is the right intuition and you are essentially done. You just have to phrase it in mathematical symbols: Write $p$ for the projection and $[c]$ for the equivalence class given by $(a,b)$. Let $V_a \subseteq X/A$ be any open neighborhood of $[a]\in X/A$, know $U_a = p^{-1}(V_a) \subseteq X$ open (since $p$ quotient map) and since $a\in\partial(a,b)$ exists $x\in U_a \cap (a,b)$, therefore $[c]=p(x) \in p(U_a)=V_a$. This shows there is no open neighborhood $V_a$ of $[a]$ not containing $[c]$, in particular $X/A$ is not Hausdorff.